# Extract fields in python when all we have is their positions and no delimiter

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, data-extraction

[image]

Hi, I have .txt file for public data in this format with no delimiters. All I have is the headers of the fields based on their positions. Example:

```
          1- 2       FIPS State code (00 for US record)
          4- 8       District ID
         10-81       District Name
```

I am trying to load data to Tableau but the column values get messed up. Especially, the Name values get split which is okay but they shift right into the 4th column.

Can someone please help me what is the best way to extract these fields in python when all we have is their positions?

Comment: Do `fips=myrecord[0:2]; dist=myrecord[3:8]` and so on. Remember that Python indexes are zero-based.

Comment: Thank you. Is myrecord this? data_df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', index_col=0, header=None) for myrecord in data_df.iterrows():

Comment: You are calling `read_csv()` but your file is *not* a `.csv`.    You will need to write code that reads the textfile line by line and picks the fields apart explicitly.

Comment: I guess even for text files we can still use read_csv() but the values need to have a delimiter like space or a ","?

Comment: If it has a consistent field delimiter, yes. But your file doesn't.

Comment: When I wrote "your file is not a `.csv`", I didn’t  mean the file extension. I meant the form of the data in the file, which is not what `read_csv()` is expecting.